# Monotone differentiable function whose derivative is discontinuous on a full measure set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a monotone function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ that is differentiable everywhere, but its derivative is discontinuous a.e.?

Comment: [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is differentiable everywhere and discontinuous on a set of positive measure. Since it also has bounded derivatives, you can add a linear function to it to make it monotone. If you work a bit harder probably you can also make it full measure. Certainly without the monotone assumption the result holds (see [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/1543)).

Comment: @willie: I guess you want to say, ``and its derivative is discontinuous on a set of positive measure''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the [Pompeiu function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative) (Feel free to add questions on the details of the construction).

Comment: Thank you! What a nice construction. I assume one has to do some extra work to make the set of discontinuity measure 1?

Comment: @Nate River: To get the discontinuity set to have measure $1$ (i.e. the continuity set to have measure $0),$ or even more extreme to get the continuity set to have Hausdorff $h$-measure zero for any specified (in advance) Hausdorff measure function $h$ (in particular, the continuity set can have Hausdorff dimension zero, which is MUCH smaller than having Lebesgue measure zero), you only need to choose $A = \mathbb Q$ and the closed sets $F_1 \subset F_2 \subset \cdots$ **(continued)**

Comment: in Theorem 1 (top p. 56) of [this paper](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/117970/CasPestMat_103-1978-1_7.pdf) so that the $F_k$ are nowhere dense such that their union contains no rational numbers and the complement relative to $[0,1]$ of their union has Lebesgue measure zero (or has Hausdorff $h$-measure zero for the stronger version). Now use the construction in Theorem 2 (bottom p. 56), letting $A$ and $B$ be a partition of $\mathbb Q$ into two disjoint dense sets. Sufficiently "thick" Cantor sets (containing only irrationals) can be used for the sets $F_k.$